# Drop Down con valores a mano

Tags: report, pentaho

Estoy intentando usar un Drop Down pero con valores de tipo entero que yo le meto previamente de alguna forma.

Los valores sería 1,2,3,4

Al crear un parámetro, selecciono el método Drop Down pero me da la sensación de que solo le puedo meter los valores mediante una query.

Estoy usando Pentaho Report

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hay formas  de meter un origen de datos que no sean consultas sql. 
En el menú de arriba te vas a `Data -> Add Datasource -> y ahi vereis "XML" o "Table"` entre otros
Si te vas a xml le puedes meter un archivo con una estructura parecida a esta.

```
 <infs>
    <rows>
    <row rowNumber="0">
    <cod cod="01">01</cod>
    <desc cod="01">Ba</desc>
    </row>
   <row rowNumber="2">
    <cod cod="03">03</cod>
    <desc cod="03">Bala</desc>
    </row>
    </rows>
    </infs>
```

Si te vas a table, te permite meter un excel o incluso meter los valores a mano.